# Go module: go/types conf.Check return err: could not import github.com/xxx/yyy/sub

Tags: go, compiler-errors

I have a project using Go module, and the content of `go.mod` is

```
module github.com/xxx/yyy
```

Then, I create a sub directory `log` and a source file `log.go`, the project structure looks like this:

```
yyy
- go.mod
- main.go
- log
  - log.go
```

Then I write the code in `main.go`

```
import (
    "github.com/xxx/yyy/log"
    "go/ast"
    "go/build"
    "go/importer"
    "go/parser"
    "go/token"
    "go/types"
)

var fileSet  = token.NewFileSet()
func main() {
    file, err := parser.ParseFile(fileSet, "main", nil, parser.ParseComments)
    conf := types.Config{Importer: importer.Default()}
    pkg, err := conf.Check(".", fileSet, []*ast.File{file}, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Log.Fatal(err.Error()) // type error
    }
}
```

Then I build it successfully, but when I run it, it crashes and logs `could not import github.com/xxx/yyy/log`. The err comes from `conf.Check` definitely, but why does it crash? Does `go/types` not support go module?

Comment: Does clearing your `$GOPATH/bin` and `$GOPATH/pkg` directories help?

Comment: It's an import error, ie the package `github.com/xxx/yyy/log` can't be resolved. The error doesn't seem related to `conf.Check` or `go/types`?

Comment: It doesn't work. @RickyA

Comment: I build it successfully, and the log has some prefix defined in `log.Log.Fatal`, so the err comes from conf.Check definitely@nijm